# Simple download file /update it

Tags: java, android

I want to update my app without google store I have already checking if there's new version. Now I need to download and install file I don't have idea how. I saw some librares but they don't download file :(. Is there any simple idea to download file ? I saw I post about this but it didn't help me at all.. I saw Some posts with codes but this didn't work for me.

Comment: What kind of file do you wan't to download and install?

Comment: without user confirmation you can't. untill user click on install button.. only you can invoke the .apk file to install.

Comment: Apk ok so i would like to Just Open it and let user click install

Answer (score 0):

Put the app in a special directory in your web server then make a flag-version in the server and your app too. Whenever you put the new version in the special directory, just change the version. In your app side check that if the flag has changed then download it from the link.

Comment: Checking for new version is done now i just need to download file, that's my problem.

Comment: Use this:   ' Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(YOUR_WebDownloadAddress));
                startActivity(browserIntent);'

Comment: Where IT will save file?